# How to validate array key in laravel validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have following data to validate as below:

```
"retinfo": [
   {
     "ret": "000"
   },
   {
     "ret": "001"
   }
   
]
```

So, I want to validate. If I have key ret is must not null. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate array data like this way :

```
$request->validate([
     'retinfo' => 'required|array', // validate array
     'retinfo.*.ret' => 'required|integer', // validate array field
]);
```